# What is the way to represent a Lorentz tensor field?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

For a vector field one can represent this with an array of arrows.

There is a standard sort of way to represent tensors in Euclidean space as small ellipses.

Is there any standard way of representing tensors with (+-) signature? For example, perhaps small light cones? One could use ellipses as well, but this would not really give an idea of where time-like and space-like directions are at each point. Maybe an ellipse with a cross in it?

Is there a common way of representing this on a 2D plane?

Comment: Are you talking about tensors with 2 indices? They can have any number of indices.

Comment: Is your question purely about notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dan said, tensors are defined independent of signature.

For example, one can draw a field of one-forms... and that has nothing to do with the signature, unless it came from a vector field whose index was raised with a metric.
If you wish to raise or lower indices, then the metric signature plays a role in the result.

When you say "tensors in Euclidean space as small ellipses",
you are likely referring to symmetric tensors with positive eigenvalues (with eigenvectors along the axes of the ellipse) or a Riemannian-signature metric.

To answer your question:
To represent the Minkowski metric, one would probably draw a field of two-sheeted [truncated] hyperboloids (with the lightcone implied). These hyperboloids would represent one tick in the future and one tick in the past from the event where the metric is evaluated. In two dimensions, you can just use the two truncated branches of the hyperbola. (You could probably get by with just the future hyperboloid... but the base point wouldn't be easy to see.) 

[To me, "time" is more important than "space"... so I prefer emphasizing time. If you want to show "space", then you can use the one-sheeted hyperboloid that represents one "tick in space" from the base point.]

(This is by analogy with a Riemannian metric, showing the directions from the base point where the metric is equal to 1.)

Concerning other tensors...
Here is an image from Schouten's Tensor Analysis for Physicists
showing various differential forms [totally antisymmetric tensors] in three dimensions. (This is what @Dan is referring to in his last sentence.)

[image: SchoutenTensorAnalysisForPhysicists-Tensors]

Comment: Yes, that makes sense I guess. If a circle has equation $x^2+y^2=1$ then a hyperbola has equation $x^2-y^2=1$. Interesting thought. My own idea would then correspond to light=cones $x^2-y^2=0$. I guess the shape isn't really that important when it comes down to it.

Comment: You could use lightcones, as is done on spacetime diagrams near the event horizon of a black hole. While the light cone can distinguish timelike from spacelike and lightlike, you can't get timelike or spacelike measurements from it.

Comment: But wouldn't a squashed lightcone give the same information as a squashed sphere?. I mean I suppose I am thinking of a truncated lightcone rather than a theortically infinite one. Otherwise it's true that would be scale invariant!

Comment: Squashing would represent some anisotropy. Truncation could suggest a scale where the cut represents the tangent hyperplane to the unit hyperboloid with the light cone as the asymptotes.